# No JSP support when running from my {jetty.base} directory

Tags: java, jsp, jetty

I have this webapp that runs smoothly when run on Jetty, from the `{jetty.home}` directory.
However, when I try to run the same .war from the `{jetty.base}`, I get the following error :

> **HTTP ERROR 500 :** JSP support not configured

Could you please tell me how to set up JSP support so it works for both directories ?

I'm using Jetty 9.3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure it.

Sounds like you don't have `jsp` module enabled in your `${jetty.base}`

Post the results of

```
$ cd /path/to/my.base
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar --list-config
```

As for how to enable a module, you have several options on how to accomplish this. (and depending on your version of Jetty, you might even have several different JSP implementations to choose from)

Read the documentation and use the technique that best suits your needs.

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup-modules.html

Comment: It worked, thanks ! I just can't understand why jsp support was enabled for {jetty.home} and not for {jetty.base}, the config looked the same to me.